# Determining Whether Current Objects are the Same in a Nested Foreach loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, comparison, equality

I am trying to determine whether the current object within a `foreach` loop nested inside of another foreach loop, which are both iterating over the same `ArrayList`, are currently both iterating over the same object. Due to the conventions of the foreach loop, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to get the current index of the objects in the ArrayList to be able to compare the current objects for equality. Essentially, I would like to `continue` over the current object within the inner foreach loop if both of the foreach loops are currently iterating over the same object.

For example, given an `ArrayList<Object>` named `objects`:

```
for (Object a : objects) {

    for (Object b : objects) {

        //If both loops are currently iterating over the same object
        //from the ArrayList objects, skip to the next iteration of the inner
        //foreach loop
        if (a == b) {

            continue;

        }

        //If both foreach loops are not iterating over the same object
        //execute some operation

    }

}
```

Is using the `==` operator to test whether both objects that are currently being iterated over are the same object reliable, or is it better to simply use regular `for` loops instead and compare the objects based on their index?

Comment: How would you use the iterators to compare the indexes of the boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is OK to compare objects with `==` in this case, **but only if you didn't put the same object in list multiple times**. If you have same object in list on multiple places than this is not OK, and you should use standard for loop.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting point! Is there any way to compare the objects reliably, even if the object is in the list multiple times?

Comment: No, I don't think it is. I also wouldn't use `equals` because it can return true if object are equals by data (if it is implemented to work like that) which I don't think you want to do. For example if you have two strings with same value, these are two objects but equals will return true!

Comment: @KevinGurney See my answer for a way to compare the objects reliably, even if the object is in the list multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as:

```
for (Object a : objects) {

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

        if(a.equals(objects.get(i)) {

            continue;
        }

    }

}
```

that is he easiest way to do it in my eyes.

Comment: I was considering doing it this way, but is there an alternative method which will allow foreach loops to be used?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Is there a specific reason why you would like to use `foreach` loops? I personally am not a huge fan of them.

Comment: Well, I suppose mostly because foreach loops seem to align more closely with object-oriented practices than regular for loops. However, I suppose the same thing could be accomplished simply using for loops with a fairly negligible difference in implementation.

Comment: `foreach` loops are specifically for object oriented looping yes, but if feel hat it is just easier to read and see the process being accomplished. `foreach` loops do have their benefits, however in the end I feel like it is a mater of opinion, and if you're pressed for time or length of code.

Answer (score 0):

If the same object is added into the `ArrayList` multiple times the `==` equality comparison may have undesired results. To check that you are not on comparing the same indexed items of the `ArrayList` (ie: you are currently on the diagonal of the 2D matrix)

**Consider this:**

```
Iterator<Object> outerIterator, innerIterator;
outerIterator = objects.iterator();
for (int i=0; outerIterator.hasNext(); ++i) {
    a = outerIterator.next();
    innerIterator = objects.iterator();
    for(int j=0; innerIterator.hasNext(); ++j) {
        b = innerIterator.next();
        //comparing for elements for SAME index of iteration
        //NOT comparing for element equality
        if(i==j) { continue; } 
        // else do stuff with a & b
    }
}
```

**Equivalently:** (and I think prettier)

```
int i=0;
for (Object a : objects) {
    int j=0;
    for (Object b : objects) {
      //comparing for elements for SAME index of iteration
      //NOT comparing for element equality
      if (i==j) { continue; }
      //else do stuf with a & b
      ++j;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

**To Summarize:**

If you want to check for shallow equality use `a==b`.

If you want to check for deep equality use `a.equals(b)`.

If you want to check for index equality use `i==j`.